# Try to publish different post on homepage according to language using Worpdress and WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I try to modify a Wordpress template that display post on homepage. The site use WPML plugin.
Here the code I have right now, surprenamment the 'fr' posts are visible on the homepage but not the 'en'
Any ideas? Thanks.

```
 <?php
if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'):
?>
<?php
    $args = array(
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        //'meta_key' => '_ttrust_post_featured',
        //'meta_value' => true, 
        'posts_per_page' => $recent_posts_count,
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'post__in' => array(
            3986,
            3971,
            3980
        ),
        'post_type' => array(
            'post'
        )
    );
?>
<?php
elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr'):
?>
   <?php
    $args = array(
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        //'meta_key' => '_ttrust_post_featured',
        //'meta_value' => true, 
        'posts_per_page' => $recent_posts_count,
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'post__in' => array(
            2630,
            2618,
            2518
        ),
        'post_type' => array(
            'post'
        )
    );
?>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolve! the code work! I forget that I hide the section with css :hidden;